# Apache Batik No WriteAdapter is available?

Tags: svg, batik

I'm writing code to convert SVG's to PNG's:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.PNGTranscoder;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

        // read the input SVG document into TranscoderInput
        String svgURI = Paths.get(args[0]).toUri().toURL().toString();
        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgURI);
        // define OutputStream to PNG Image and attach to TranscoderOutput
        OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("out.png");
        TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);
        // create a JPEG transcoder
        PNGTranscoder t = new PNGTranscoder();
        // set the transcoding hints
        t.addTranscodingHint(SVGAbstractTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, new Float(600));
        t.addTranscodingHint(SVGAbstractTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, new Float(600));
        // convert and write output
        t.transcode(input, output);
        // flush and close the stream then exit
        ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();
    }
}
```

I get the following exceptions executing it with a variety of SVG's:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: null
Enclosed Exception:
Could not write PNG file because no WriteAdapter is availble
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(ImageTranscoder.java:132)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:142)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:156)
    at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Batik version (reported by Maven):

```
version=1.9
groupId=org.apache.xmlgraphics
artifactId=batik-transcoder
```

I get the same error with Batik 1.7.

Suggestions?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/css4j/echosvg/issues/11

Answer (score 33):

The problem was solved by Peter Coppens on the xmlgraphics-batik-users mailing list.  The problem is that the Maven repository for Batik 1.9 is missing a dependency, which can be addressed by adding to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

The cryptic exception disappears and the code functions as expected with this addition.  This was reported as a bug for Batk 1.7 (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44682).

Comment: where to find pom.xml ?

Comment: The dependencies node of my pom.xml included:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have experienced same issue with version 1.10 as well

Comment: same with version 1.11

Comment: @rumman0786: I suggest crafting a simple example (you could even copy my code above and use the newer batik as a dependency) and submit it to the mailing list (can sign up at https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/mailing-lists.html ).  When I have a chance, I can double-check which batik version the deployed version of my code is using and if the dependency has been upgraded, see if it works...

Comment: Still same in 1.13

Comment: And the same in 1.14

Comment: Reported in 2008 and still not fixed in 2024 with version 1.17. I'm glad I found this hint here.

Answer (score 1):

Still same in 1.17, solution still works (`implementation 'org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-codec:1.17'` in gradle)